# Do AF-S lenses work with bodies with in-built motors?

Tags: nikon, autofocus, af-s

I have D-5000 body (without AF motor in the body) and two AF-S lenses.
If I upgrade my body to more expensive body one with built-in AF motors, will AF-S lenses work (do autofocus) with new body ?

Thanks

Comment: Here's a useful table of what lenses are compatible with what bodies:  http://www.nikonians.org/nikon/slr-lens.html.

Answer (score 3):

In a word, yes. You might like to check out this question:
[What motor gets used if both lens and camera body have a focus motor?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10074/what-motor-gets-used-if-both-lens-and-camera-body-have-a-focus-motor)